# Any alternatives to Clirr (binary and source compatibility with older releases)?

Tags: java, api, jar, backwards-compatibility

We are using clirr(http://clirr.sourceforge.net) in our project but it looks very outdated. 
I've tried to search for any alternatives, but they are in the same position:

- JDiff(http://jdiff.sourceforge.net)
- Jar Compare(http://extradata.com/products/jarc/)

So, I'm looking for community help: how are you solving a problem of checking source and binary compatibility?

Comment: In this talk  "Lukáš Krejčí - Evolving APIs in Java" described not only the problem of compatibility but also short introduction of tools 
https://youtu.be/z_3VLU7pvY0?t=1253

It looks like the most right tool to use today is RevAPI and they even provide an online diff tool https://diff.revapi.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also try [japicmp](https://github.com/siom79/japicmp), it's a neat project I found recently while trying to perform the same task.

Its usage is pretty simple and it comes down to passing it two versions of your library packaged as JARs... for example:

```
java -jar japicmp-0.0.2.jar -n my-jar-new.jar -o my-jar-old.jar
```

It also has an API that allows you to use it programmatically.

The project's [Github page](https://github.com/siom79/japicmp) has a straightforward guide on how to get started.

---

Also, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5337179/1407656) suggests [jarc](http://www.extradata.com/products/jarc/) as an alternative

Comment: Thank you! Looks very handy!

Comment: japicmp is great, very easy to add into a maven pom which allows it to obtain the jar dependencies very easily.

Answer (score 3):

Tools to check compatibility of Java APIs:

- [japi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker)
- [japitools](http://www.sab39.org/Software/Japitools/42/)
- [sigtest](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/SigTest)

  - [SigTest](http://wiki.netbeans.org/SigTest), a NetBeans fork of sigtest
- [japi-checker](https://github.com/trohovsky/japi-checker)
- [japicmp](https://github.com/siom79/japicmp)
- [revapi](https://revapi.org/)

Tools to check compatibility of OSGi bundles:

- [bnd-baseline-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/maven/bnd-baseline-maven-plugin)

Tools to visualize changes in JARs:

- [pkgdiff](http://lvc.github.com/pkgdiff/)

See also ["Evolving Java-based APIs 2: Achieving API Binary Compatibility"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Evolving_Java-based_APIs_2) paper for detailed info about possible binary and source compatibility issues in Java APIs.

Comment: Sorry for accidentally pushing the edit through. I did not realize I now have enough reputation not to require review. I wonder if is possible for me to somehow still do suggested edits that go into review queue...