# sonarqube - CLIRR Plugin alternative

Tags: sonarqube

I took a look on the Clirr Plugin (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Clirr+Plugin). However, according to 
[Any alternatives to Clirr (binary and source compatibility with older releases)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863710/any-alternatives-to-clirr-binary-and-source-compatibility-with-older-releases) , clirr is rather dated.
Are any of the alternatives compatible to clirr?

best,
Roman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there's no SonarQube plugin for a tool that's less dated than Clirr.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Do you know whether CLIRR still works with Java8 and new features etc.